# Why does firebase asks for read access in order to write something into a collection?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Why does the firebase asks me for reading permision in order to write something in a collection?

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
            setDoc(doc(db, "UserOrders", {arguments[4] + 1}), {
                name: arguments[0],
                lastname: arguments[1],
                image: arguments[2],
                contact: arguments[3],
                orderNumber: arguments[4] + 1
            });
```

Obviously it is supposed to write some information into a collection, and it has nothing to do with the read property, but when i attempt to execute this code i get the next error;

[image]

Here are my firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not `allow read, write`? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: Can you share what the `arguments` array is? `doc(db, "UserOrders", {arguments[4] + 1})` How does `{ arguments[4] + 1 }` resolve to a string i.e. the document ID?

Comment: @MartinZeitler because i do not want the users with all the information from the browser to read this file from his side.

Comment: @dharmaraj It is just a string that sets the document name in the collection

Comment: I have tried your code and rules on my end and don't catch any permission error. Do you have multiple projects in Firebase? Have you checked if your Firebase config set in your code points to the correct project? If not, it will result in a permission error as it is not getting the correct Firestore Security Rules.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB I havew just one firebase project, so i do not think this is the matter.

Comment: Your code and rules above shouldn't have any problems and as stated by @FrankvanPuffelen , give us a better source that describes that behavior. I would suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to investigate your issue further.

Comment: Your rules only allow `create`, not `update`. Are you sure the document doesn't exist yet?